# Why do we use LSB below 10 MHz and USB above 10 MHz when operating SSB HF?

Tags: hf, ssb

As a relatively new ham operator, I understand that it is customary to use lower-sideband below 10 MHz and upper-side band above 10Mhz when operating single-sideband HF. I'm curious how we got to such a standard instead of just picking one or the other for all bands.

To further complicate it for new hams, it seems that RTTY operators use lower-sideband everywhere and PSK operators use upper-sideband everywhere. ([Reference](http://www.brats-qth.org/training/advanced/operate5.htm))

Is there any technical reason not to use upper-sideband everywhere? Or is this purely tradition to be passed on for the sake of tradition? Does anyone know some verifiable history for how this de-facto standard came to be?

Comment: This question was asked and answered in the most recent QST magazine.  I think it was the May issue.  As usual though, I ignored the article and continued my 5 minute browse before tossing the magazine in recycle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Amateur Radio operators use this rule of thumb for historical technical reasons. [SM0AOM on the QRZ forums writes](http://forums.qrz.com/archive/index.php/t-312177.html):

> The changing of ISB sideband positions at 10 MHz actually has an engineering background.
>
> In the earliest ISB exciters, it was found appropriate to change the final mixer scheme from subtraction to
>   addition mixing at around 10 MHz due to spurious suppression concerns.
>   This sometimes caused interoperability problems in international point-to-point ISB circuits.
>
> To overcome this, a practice was formalized in 1959 by the ITU/CCIR as the Recommendation 249, which prescribed
>   that the ISB sideband positions could either automatically or manually be interchanged when the output frequency went through
>   10 MHz. An often quoted reference where ISB exciter design considerations are handled with German thoroughness is
>   W Kleische: "Fernbedienbarer Steuervorsatz für Kurzwellen-Nachrichtensender" in "Telefunken-Zeitung" December 1962.
>
> Later advances in exciter design made this Recommendation obsolete, and later generations of exciters only had this facility as an option, and current production ISB equipment lacks it entirely.

Comment: I think that there was also a practical reason to do so, apart from any ITU rules. Most, if not all amateur equipment used 9 MHz as IF. Mixing 80m and 40m up and the rest down towards 9 MHz in simple transceivers with one BFO (Beat Frequency Oscillator) was a logical solution.

Comment: A long discussion of this on QRZ: https://forums.qrz.com/index.php?threads/an-urban-legend-disproved.462916/

Answer (score 2):

> I think that there was also a practical reason to do so, apart from
>   any ITU rules. Most, if not all amateur equipment used 9 MHz as IF.
>   Mixing 80m and 40m up and the rest down towards 9 MHz in simple
>   transceivers with one BFO (Beat Frequency Oscillator) was a logical
>   solution. – jcoppens Nov 14 '14 at 12:56

Unfortunately, this is an incorrect answer, but one which I believed as legend until I recently simulated the heterodyning of an SSB signal up and down in frequency. The "sense" of the sideband does not change, regardless of the "direction" of the frequency conversion.

Comment: A EE lab team built a few of these at Texas A&M in the 1950s. The XTAL osc was at 5 mc.  A DSB signal was generated and filtered to USB using WWII surplus XTALs. The BFO covered 8.x - 9.x mc.  BFO minus USB covered 75m LSB. BFO plus USB covered 20m USB. They also experimented with reduced carrier DSB and inverted audio DSB.